# Uploading files using object model

Tags: security, document, file-upload

I'm experiencing some problems adding documents to a library using the object model. 
I use the spfolder.files.add where I pass a filestream containing the document in. When I run my Internet Explorer as administrator, all works fine. When I run it normally it doesn't want to open a filestream to the documents. Any suggestions? I use Kerberos as security protocol.
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste the code here please?

Answer (score 0):

Using object model check this code to upload document to document library from local network.

```
 String fileToUpload = @"C:\YourFile.txt";
    String sharePointSite = "http://yoursite.com/sites/Research/";
    String documentLibraryName = "Shared Documents";

    using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(sharePointSite))
    {
        using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
        {
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileToUpload))
                throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.", fileToUpload);                    

            SPFolder myLibrary = oWeb.Folders[documentLibraryName];

            // Prepare to upload
            Boolean replaceExistingFiles = true;
            String fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload);
            FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileToUpload);

            // Upload document
            SPFile spfile = myLibrary.Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, replaceExistingFiles);

            // Commit 
            myLibrary.Update();
        }
    }
```

If you want to upload without permission then put hole code in

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    // implementation of full code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used the same code as you did, but I'll give the RunWithElevatedPrivileges a try